# Create a weighted adjacency list from an alphanumeric edgelist in Python

Tags: python, r, adjacency-matrix, nodelist

I've been working on this dataset of protein-protein interactions.  I have the edgelist in the following format:

```
AIG676464 AIG8475985 0.00035. Protein 1, Protein 2, weight.
```

I've tried several methods and can't get it to output the matrix. What I am hoping to get is the matrix form of the interactions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Python or R is fine.

I've tried networkx:

```
import networkx as nx

fh = open("InWeb29.txt", 'rb')
#d = fh.write(textline)
#fh.close()

G = nx.read_edgelist(fh)
G = nx.Graph([()])
A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
print(A.todense())
A.setdiag(A.diagonal()*2)
print(A.todense())
```

Here is my other code so far:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

"Load in data file"
"""Read in the data file"""

df = pd.read_csv("datafile.txt", sep= '\t', header=0)
headers = list(df)
prot1 = df[df.columns[0]]
prot2 = df[df.columns[1]]
weight = df[df.columns[2]]
print prot1
with open("datafile.txt") as f:
    next(f)
    data = [tuple(map(str,row)) for row in csv.reader(f)]

n = max(max(prot1, prot2) for prot1, prot2, weight in data)
matrix = [[None]* n for i in range(n)] 

for prot1, prot2 in data:
    matrix[prot1][prot2]= weight

for row in matrix:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Please add a short paste of test data and the desired output from the test set.

Comment: If you're cool working in the `igraph` framework in R, `get.adjacency()` may help.

Comment: Will give it a another try.

Comment: That seemed to work without the weights.

Answer (score 1):

It NetworkX you can use `read_weighted_edgelist`

```
import networkx as nx
import StringIO

s = StringIO.StringIO("AIG676464 AIG8475985 0.00035")

G = nx.read_weighted_edgelist(s)
A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)

print A.todense()
```

Output

```
[[ 0.       0.00035]
 [ 0.00035  0.     ]]
```

Comment: Ok, that's exactly what I want Aric! Thanks so much!!  Thank you all for your help!!  Going to try this now!